# What information is returned by stripe API

Tags: php, api, stripe-payments

On the stripe website it says I can store any information returned by the stripe API in my own database. However I cannot find out what information the stripe API returns from the website.

I am expecting to see some of these:

- CVC
- Last 4 digits of CC

But can anyone tell me what the full response would be on successful payment?

Comment: CVC is probably the number one thing that you *shouldn't* store in your own database.

Comment: Anything returned from the API is perfectly fine, it's not an issue to store the CVC at all @EdHinchliffe

Comment: @JamesWillson it isn't returned by the API, and should **not** be stored. See [here](https://www.pcisecuritystandards.org/pdfs/pci_fs_data_storage.pdf), or just google it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Sample request made from the following example,**

```
require_once('./lib/Stripe.php');   
Stripe::setApiKey("sk_test_BQokikJOvBiI2HlWgH4olfQ2");   
Stripe_Charge::create(  
  array( "amount" => 400,   
         "currency" => "usd",   
         "card" => "tok_14Z9t42eZvKYlo2CbJqWYQrT", // obtained with Stripe.js,   
         "metadata" => array("order_id" => "6735")   
));
```

**From the API documentation of Stripe API the following would be the response,**

{
  "id": "ch_14ZKti2eZvKYlo2CXVZ58Tno",
  "object": "charge",
  "created": 1409916538,
  "livemode": false,
  "paid": true,
  "amount": 1200,
  "currency": "usd",
  "refunded": false,
  "card": {
    "id": "card_14ZKtM2eZvKYlo2CJIxNJiZq",
    "object": "card",
    "last4": "4242",
    "brand": "Visa",
    "funding": "credit",
    "exp_month": 9,
    "exp_year": 2014,
    "fingerprint": "Xt5EWLLDS7FJjR1c",
    "country": "US",
    "name": "Test",
    "address_line1": null,
    "address_line2": null,
    "address_city": null,
    "address_state": null,
    "address_zip": null,
    "address_country": null,
    "cvc_check": "pass",
    "address_line1_check": null,
    "address_zip_check": null,
    "customer": "cus_4heg86QFWN3sVn"
  },
  "captured": true,
  "refunds": {
    "object": "list",
    "total_count": 0,
    "has_more": false,
    "url": "/v1/charges/ch_14ZKti2eZvKYlo2CXVZ58Tno/refunds",
    "data": []
  },
  "balance_transaction": "txn_14WzKB2eZvKYlo2CIbBDo1SD",
  "failure_message": null,
  "failure_code": null,
  "amount_refunded": 0,
  "customer": "cus_4heg86QFWN3sVn",
  "invoice": null,
  "description": null,
  "dispute": null,
  "metadata": {
    "order_id": "6735"
  },
  "statement_description": null,
  "receipt_email": null
}

For more information on the API Document you can visit [stripe docs](https://stripe.com/docs/api?lang=php#metadata)